# linux big file removed but disk space not released

Tags: linux, sendmail

My Ubuntu Linux 14.04 server is under attacked which may be caused by an outdated Drupal site. It tries to send a lot of email. /var/log/mail.log file grows very fast at least 5G. The server's disk become 100% full and out of service.

I shut down sendmail service by `service stop sendmail`, uninstall it by `apt-get remove sendmail`, kill all existing process and remove some old log files to release disk space. But I still find that mail.log is still growing.

I delete mail.log but find disk space not released. I `cd /; du -sh *` and confirm that about 5G space is disappeared.

Any idea how to recover that 5G space (I have only 20G space on the server)? I am also worry about mail logs are still writing to that missing file. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can try doing `lsof` and looking for the mail log you deleted, it would should you the PID that still has it open if there is one

Comment: Thank you! I found it using by syslog and I successfuly released the space by `service rsyslog restart`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **lsof** command to find out which process is writing to the log file, then terminate the process. The missing 5G space could be because the process still has the file open in output mode. Once the process terminates, the space should appear

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar problem. You need look to bd size, is bd USE 5GB you need install [optimizedb](https://www.drupal.org/project/optimizedb) module and clean all cash. If not BD, look's **var/spool/mqueue** directory.